# ClearInterval that is inside a setTimeout not working

Tags: jquery, settimeout, fadein, setinterval, clearinterval

I am having this code:

```
 function myf(){    
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(flag === 1){
            sleep = 1;
        }else{
            sleep = 0;
        }
        myMove();
        myf();      
  }, 6000); 

  function myMove(){
      var intId = setInterval(function(){
        if(sleep === 0){
             clearInterval(intId);
             return false;
        }else{
             $("#myDiv1").fadeIn(1000);
             $("#myDiv1").fadeOut(1000);
        }
      }, 1000);
   }
```

My problem is that the clearInterval is not working. So when I am in else case (and I am going there, I have tested that, so the if case works fine) then my div "myDiv1" continues to fade in and out. How can I stop this interval?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in your syntax. Should be:

```
if (flag === 1) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks but this is just a typo. Sorry for that I will change it. It is right however on my project. So this is not the problem

Answer (score 2):

it will never called clear interval function as your setinterval function is

```
intId = setInterval(function(){
                $("#myDiv1").fadeIn(1000);
                $("#myDiv1").fadeOut(1000);
           }, 1000);
```

so this code will get called after every time interval.. in that function you have to check for flag and then you have to write kill interval function..

something like

```
intId = setInterval( function(){
                if(flag==1) 
{
                $("#myDiv1").fadeIn(1000);
                $("#myDiv1").fadeOut(1000);
}

else
{
// clearInterval here
}
           }, 1000);
```

Comment: ok I change my code, you can see above. But still is not working.

Comment: where you are resetting flat to 0?? I am assuming flag=1 initially.

Comment: when I console.log the sleep just before the setInterval line, I am getting the right value, changing between 0 and 1. So the if case with "flag" works ok.

Comment: what is your exact requirement?? when you want to show those div's and when you want to close them (time interval).. right now you have 2 loops. one running after every 6 seconds and 1 running after every 1 second(after those 6 seconds when setinterval will get called.)
anyways.. this may work fine.. 

http://jsfiddle.net/wRhFu/

Comment: the first loop changes the background on my page. So when the background has an id and then the flag==1, then I want to second loop to start running every 1 sec (like an image changing every one sec) until the first background loses its id so we have flag=0.

Comment: anyway the only solution I found, is to stop the setInterval after 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize your `intId` variable using `var`:

```
var intId = setInterval(function(){
```